# How to calculate change between conditional elements in panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of Open, High, Low, Close prices for 30 securities every five minutes in a dataframe. Here is a sample:

```
                     Close   High    Low   Open Symbol
2015-03-18 14:05:00  75.99  75.99  75.73  75.76     DD
2015-03-18 14:05:00  82.82  82.85  82.55  82.55    WMT
2015-03-18 14:05:00  25.72  25.72  25.62  25.64     GE
2015-03-18 14:05:00  61.94  61.95  61.62  61.62    JPM
2015-03-18 14:10:00  26.72  26.72  26.62  26.64     GE
2015-03-18 14:10:00  62.94  62.95  62.62  62.62    JPM
2015-03-18 14:10:00  83.82  83.85  83.55  83.55    WMT
2015-03-18 14:10:00  73.99  73.99  73.73  73.76     DD
```

I want to take the Open values for each symbol at each timestamp, and subtract them from the Close at the previous timestamp for that symbol so to measure the gap. For example, I would take the 14:10 timestamped Open value for DD and subtract it from the 14:05 timestamped Close value for DD.

I have found solutions for data which is uniform, i.e. if this dataframe was for only one symbol, but given that I have 30 symbols in this dataframe, what would be the best way to calculate this 'Gap' value?

Thank you,

CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'Symbol' and then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) passing a lambda and use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift):

```
In [147]:
df.groupby('Symbol').apply(lambda x: x['Open'] - x['Close'].shift())

Out[147]:
index   2015-03-18 14:05:00  2015-03-18 14:10:00
Symbol                                          
DD                      NaN                -2.23
GE                      NaN                 0.92
JPM                     NaN                 0.68
WMT                     NaN                 0.73
```

**EDIT**

To add this as a new column, you can groupby as above and call `transform` on the 2 columns of interest and index the 'Close' column. `tranform` returns a Series aligned to the original df:

```
In [19]:
df['New_col'] = df.groupby('Symbol')[['Open','Close']].transform(lambda x: x['Open'] - x['Close'].shift())['Close']
df

Out[19]:
                     Close   High    Low   Open Symbol  New_col
index                                                          
2015-03-18 14:05:00  75.99  75.99  75.73  75.76     DD    -2.23
2015-03-18 14:05:00  82.82  82.85  82.55  82.55    WMT     0.73
2015-03-18 14:05:00  25.72  25.72  25.62  25.64     GE     0.92
2015-03-18 14:05:00  61.94  61.95  61.62  61.62    JPM     0.68
2015-03-18 14:10:00  26.72  26.72  26.62  26.64     GE     0.92
2015-03-18 14:10:00  62.94  62.95  62.62  62.62    JPM     0.68
2015-03-18 14:10:00  83.82  83.85  83.55  83.55    WMT     0.73
2015-03-18 14:10:00  73.99  73.99  73.73  73.76     DD    -2.23
```

Comment: This is great, do you have a recommendation for a method to integrate this back into my dataframe as a fifth column?